# Laptop won't start due to "electrical static"

Tags: laptop

So I have an Aver s7 laptop, and when I turn it on the fan starts but it shows a black screen.  Called support and they said it's out of warranty but it's a known problem with static electricity.  I've now taken the laptop apart and tried unplugging the battery, but no dice.

It seems likely that the laptop is still roughly functional but is having an error on bootup, does anyone have any other suggestions to try?  I know "static electricity" is vague but I'm open to try anything

Comment: A common failure in LCD monitors, such as the one built into most laptops, is that the fluorescent backlight fails to start.  The LCD image part still works, as can be seen by close inspection with a flashlight, and some people have used this as an excuse to make a DIY projector out of it.  Or you could just have the backlight fixed.  I doubt it's ESD-related.

Comment: CRTs did build up charge, and needed occasional Degaussing, but LCDs do not work the same way and don't generally accumulate charge.

Comment: Are you able to find out whether it can boot normally with one or more of the following signs even if there is nothing displayed? (1) HDD LED is irregaularly flashing as if hard drive is in use. (2) If you are pressing NumLock, CapsLock or ScrollLock, their LED indicators react (3) There is a beep on power up (4) Image is displayed on external monitor, if attached.

Comment: static electricity can cause permanent damage to electrnics.  If they suspect static electricity then your hardware, and your laptop isn't working, then you are out of luck.